# Easy generating functions task from concrete mathematics book

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

This question might seem very novice, but i'm not sure about the solution.

We have domino puzzle of size $2 \times\ n$ and we get 4 points for every vertical block
and 1 point for horizontal block, every block is size of $2 \times 1$. How many possibilities are there to get exactly $m$ points? For $m=6$ there are 3 possibilities, $\text{VHH}$,$\text{HHV}$,$\text{HHHHHH}$

My attempt:
I know it's easy to make this task without generating functions, but it's just an exercise for G.F.

Let's make sequences$$a_n = <1, x^2, x^4, x^6, x^8,\dots >$$
                    $$b_n = <1,x^4,x^8,x^{12},x^{16},\dots>$$

Exponential generating function(egf) for $a_n$ will be $$\sum a_n\frac{z^n}{n!}$$
and for $b_n$ will be $$\sum b_n\frac{z^n}{n!}$$

And multiplying those two series should give us some new series and answer for $m$(excluding odd $m$ of course, answer here is always 0) is coefficient standing next to $z^m$, but i'm not getting true answer for any $m$. I'd appreciate some help on this task, thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for any inaccuracy, but those points have to sum up to $m$. It is, if we have $m=6$ then we can take one verical block and get 4 points and after that we have to get two horizontal blocks and get 2 points. $4+2=6$. Sorry but i don't really know what is unclear and there are errors in my solution, so don't take this as a hint to correct solution.

Comment: Consider the non-commutative series $f(x,y)=1+x+x^2+y+x^3+xy+...$ of all possible $2\times n$ tillings where $x$ represents putting a vertical domino, and $y$ putting two horizontal ones. We get that $f(x,y)=1+xf(x,y)+yf(y,x)$. Now put $x=t^4$ and $y=t^2$, solve for $g(t)=f(t^4,t^2)$, expand it in series and the coefficient of $t^m$. is the answer.

Comment: One question! Now I noticed there is an interpretation that is not answered as above. The above answer is the number of ways to earn $m$ points. But maybe you meant earning $m$ points, with a $2\times n$ board. Is that the case?

Comment: we have to use $2\times n$ board. 
It's like... we make every possible board for any $n$ and we search how many boards have exactly $m$ points

Comment: Actually wait: with VHH, how do you get 3 points? Doesn't the V already contribute at least 4 to the number of points?

Comment: Oh, that stupid typo... it should be $m=6$ of course, sorry

Comment: Ah, if it is just about the points it is the answer above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tile a $2 \times n$ board, horizontal ($1 \times 2$) blocks must always be used in pairs, one below the other.

As we care about both size (width) and "points", we need a *bivariate* generating function. Let's use the variable $z$ to mark size, and $u$ to mark points. Then a vertical block corresponds to $zu^4$, and a pair of horizontal block corresponds to $z^2u^2$. Any tiling is a *sequence* of these, so the class of all configurations is

$$\mathcal{C} = \operatorname{S\scriptsize EQ}(\mathcal{V} + \mathcal{HH}) \implies C(z, u) = \frac{1}{1 - (zu^4 + z^2u^2)}$$

The coefficient of $z^nu^m$ in $C(z)$ gives the answer (number of ways to tile a $2 \times n$ board, and get exactly $m$ points).

If you want to allow all possible values of $n$, just set $z = 1$: then we have

$$C(u) = \frac{1}{1-(u^4 + u^2)} = 1 + u^2 + 2u^4 +3u^6 + 5u^8 + O(u^{10})$$

and you look at the coefficient of $u^m$ in it: indeed the coefficient of $u^6$ is $3$.

Comment: That's really clever and now i see the solution! Marked as an answer. If you are willing to answer my following thoughts i will be really greatful.

Meanwhile i tried to get solution from pure combinatorics approach. 
It is... 

Let's make sequence $a_n = <1,x^2,2x^4,3x^6,4x^8,\dots>$ and $b_n = < 1,x^4,2x^8,3x^{12},4x^{16},\dots >$ it is, $a*x^q$ coefficient $a$ means how many blocks are there of value $q$. 
So if we take $m=10$ we can take any two $ax^q$ from $a_n$, $bx^w$ from $b_n$ that $q+w=m$ and from combinatorics we can tell there is $\frac{(a+b)!}{a!b!}$ many possibilites

Comment: And i was wondering, how can we get correct generating function from this solution?